# Parse.com push notification when phone locked(android)

Tags: android, parse-platform, push

Sorry for my english. Can you tell me how i can like this: i have locked phone, if notifications is push when phone locked its show(just like you were getting a call). I use Parse.com

Its my settings:

```
 // Initialize Crash Reporting.
    ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, "-", "-");

    //ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
    // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

**Manifest**

```
 <receiver android:name="----Receiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Receiver**

```
 @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);
        //String uriString = null;

        try {

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            if (extras != null) {
                String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");
                JSONObject json;

                Log.e("json", json.toString());

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `ParseApplication` class that extends `Application` and initialize in this class the Parse sdk and delete it from your activity.

Then, as this line to the `application` attribute on the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:name=".ParseApplication"
```